# Unable to Find Entrypoint For Nextcloud (Alpine-based Version) For a Cron Container

Tags: shell, docker

I'm using Docker with Rancher v1.6, setting up a Nextcloud stack.

I would like to use a dedicated container for running cron tasks every 15 minutes.

The "normal" Nextcloud Docker image can simply use the following:

```
entrypoint: |
  bash -c 'bash -s <<EOF
  trap "break;exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM
  while /bin/true; do
    su -s "/bin/bash" -c "/usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/cron.php" www-data
    echo $$(date) - Running cron finished
    sleep 900
  done
  EOF'
```

(Pulled from this [GitHub post](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/36#issuecomment-432709156))

However, the Alpine-based image does not have `bash`, and so it cannot be used.

I found [this script](https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/00387f5a7d439d94c01c1ebe27959ce9e967671e/15.0/fpm-alpine/cron.sh) in the list of examples:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

exec busybox crond -f -l 0 -L /dev/stdout
```

However, I cannot seem to get that working with my docker-compose.yml file.
I don't want to use an external file, just to have the script entirely in the docker-compose.yml file, to make preparation and changes a bit easier.

Thank you!

Comment: alpine has `sh` or `ash`, does it matter that much? Can't you install bash if you need it `apt update; apg add bash` ? Why do you run bash in bash and then do su with explicit bash? Why don't just `sh -c 'command1; command2;'` ?

Comment: Personally, I'd write a shell script, and build a very small custom image that COPYs it in and runs it as the CMD.  That's much more testable (you can just run the shell script on the host, or just `docker run` the image) and won't have nearly so many layers of nested shells.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm not familiar enough with the writing scripts for sh/ash/bash to be able to make it functional (or I'm doing something wrong). Also, the example with bash is there simply because that's what many others use for non-alpine-based images, and as mentioned before, I'm not experienced enough writing scripts yet to be able to answer your question of why it's written that way.

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm definitely open to other ways of accomplishing getting the cron task done, but I have yet to get into building my own images, and so have simply been using official ones only.

Comment: just change bash to sh

Comment: @KamilCuk Can't believe it was that simple... Thank you! I'll definitely give you the answer if you'd like!